# IPv6 network connectivity - Configuration issues

Tags: networking, ipv6, ospf, quagga

I have a simple network as shown in the attached figure. I am having connectivity issues between different end hosts. Can anybody spot what might be the problem? I am using Linux machines as Routers with Quagga installed. Quagga is using OSPF for IPv6 routing in this scenario. 
[IPv6 Network can be seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaZwl.jpg)

R = Router

V,DNS,CMS,C are normal linux machines

R1 is connected to two networks through R2 and R3.

R2, R3, R4, and R4 are connected together using a switch (The middle horizontal line in the diagram shown). The question is also that how should I configure the prefixes here?

An example ospf6 configuration of R4 is

```
interface eth4
 ipv6 ospf6 network broadcast
!
router ospf6
 router-id 0.0.0.4
 redistribute static route-map static-ospf6
 redistribute connected
 area 0.0.0.0 range 2001:4::/64
 area 0.0.0.1 range 2001:5::/64
 interface fxp0 area 0.0.0.0
 interface eth4 area 0.0.0.0
 interface eth5 area 0.0.0.1
```

I have statically configured the interfaces on the all the machines. 
Each end-machine has a gateway configured in routing as well (the attached router). Each router has ipv6 forwarding enabled as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you used tcpdump or wireshark to confirm if any of the routers are actually forwarding traffic? Also, have you tried disabling quagga and used static routes to test a basic scenario e.g. try and make `DNS` connect to `C` by putting appropriate routes on `R5` + `R4`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, sorry to reply a bit late. Yes, the static routes work just fine. All host reachable.